# Update if document exists, otherwise create a new document in faunadb

Tags: faunadb

Trying to update a document if it exists, otherwise create a document with the same data. I need to do this using an `Index` rather than a direct `Ref` as well.

Using this to update in cases where I know for certain it already exists. But in this case, since it cannot be know for sure if the `Ref` exists, it throws an error. Tried checking if the `Ref` exists, but that doesn't work because the `Get` fails.

```
q.Update(
  q.Select(["ref"], q.Get(q.Match(q.Index("fromUUID"), request.UUID))),
  {
    data: request
  }
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checking if the Ref exists is the right approach, but you should use `q.Exists` instead of `Get` (which will fail as you have discovered. You can also use `q.Let` to avoid some repetition. Something like the below:

```
q.Let({
    match: q.Match(q.Index('fromUUID'), request.UUID),
    data: { data: request }
  },
  q.If(
    q.Exists(q.Var('match')),
    q.Update(q.Select('ref', q.Get(q.Var('match'))), q.Var('data')),
    q.Create(q.Collection('Foos'), q.Var('data'))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can implement the upsert that way:

```
Let(
  {
    UUID: '611c798e-24c8-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002',
    doc: Match('fromUUID',Var('UUID')),
    upsert: If(Exists(Var('doc')),Update(Select(['ref'],Get(Var('doc'))),{data:{val1:10,val2:20}}),Create(Collection('stackoverflow'),{data:{val1:1,val2:2,uuid:Var('UUID')}}))
  },
  Var('upsert')
)
```

The index search for an UUID in the collection, if exists, update the document. If not, create a new document with the UUID plus any field/value pairs.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Luigi